# How to cancel sent invitation on LinkedIn via Android app?

Tags: applications

Is it possible to cancel a sent invitation on LinkedIn via the Android app? It [can be done through the website](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&es_sm=122&q=cancel+invite+linkedin+&oq=cancel+invite+linkedin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so, consider the following steps:

> 1. Go to your LinkedIn Inbox and click “Sent” to see the invitations you have sent.
> 2. Find any invitation that has not yet been accepted and click on the subject line of the message.
> 3. Click “Withdraw”

[Source](http://www.lawtechnologytoday.org/2014/01/withdrawing-invitations-to-connect-on-linkedin/)